# Custom duplicate removal strategy with Spark joins

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I've more than 2 tables and I wish to join them and create a single table where queries will be faster.

Table-1

```
---------------
user  | activityId
---------------
user1 | 123
user2 | 123
user3 | 123
user4 | 123
user5 | 123
---------------
```

Table-2

```
---------------------------------
user  | activityId | event-1-time
---------------------------------
user2 | 123        | 1001
user2 | 123        | 1002
user3 | 123        | 1003
user5 | 123        | 1004
---------------------------------
```

Table-3

```
---------------------------------
user  | activityId | event-2-time
---------------------------------
user2 | 123        | 10001
user5 | 123        | 10002
---------------------------------
```

Left join on table-1 over (user,activityId) with table-2 & table-3 will produce result like:

Joined-data

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
user  | activityId | event-1 | event-1-time | event-2 | event-2-time
--------------------------------------------------------------------
user1 | 123        | 0       | null         | 0       | null
user2 | 123        | 1       | 1001         | 1       | 10001
user2 | 123        | 1       | 1002         | 1       | 10001
user3 | 123        | 1       | 1003         | 0       | null
user4 | 123        | 0       | null         | 0       | null
user5 | 123        | 1       | 1004         | 1       | 10002
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I wish to remove the redundancy introduced with event-2 with same time i.e. event-2 appeared only once but reported twice since event-1 appeared twice.

In other words user and activityId grouped records should be distinct at every table level.

I want following output. I do not care about relationship(event-1 with event-2). Is there anything which allows to customize join and achieve this behavior

---

```
user  | activityId | event-1 | event-1-time | event-2 | event-2-time
--------------------------------------------------------------------
user1 | 123        | 0       | null         | 0       | null
user2 | 123        | 1       | 1001         | 1       | 10001
user2 | 123        | 1       | 1002         | 0       | null
user3 | 123        | 1       | 1003         | 0       | null
user4 | 123        | 0       | null         | 0       | null
user5 | 123        | 1       | 1004         | 1       | 10002
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Edit:**

I'm using Scala for joining these tables. Query used:

```scala
val joined = table1.join(table2, Seq("user","activityId"), "left").join(table3, Seq("user","activityId"), "left")

joined.select(table1("user"), table1("activityId"), when(table2("activityId").isNull,0).otherwise(1) as "event-1", 
table2("timestamp") as "event-1-time"), when(table3("activityId").isNull, 0).otherwise(1) as "event-2", table3("timestamp") as "event-2-time").show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should create an *additional column* populating with *row index* for *each group of user* *ordering by `activityId`* and then use that added column in the `outer join` process**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy("activityId")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val tempTable1 = table1.withColumn("rowNumber", row_number().over(windowSpec))
val tempTable2 = table2.withColumn("rowNumber", row_number().over(windowSpec)).withColumn("event-1", lit(1))
val tempTable3 = table3.withColumn("rowNumber", row_number().over(windowSpec)).withColumn("event-2", lit(1))

tempTable1
    .join(tempTable2, Seq("user", "activityId", "rowNumber"), "outer")
    .join(tempTable3, Seq("user", "activityId", "rowNumber"), "outer")
    .drop("rowNumber")
    .na.fill(0)
```

You should get your desired output `dataframe` as

```
+-----+----------+------------+-------+------------+-------+
|user |activityId|event-1-time|event-1|event-2-time|event-2|
+-----+----------+------------+-------+------------+-------+
|user1|123       |null        |0      |null        |0      |
|user2|123       |1002        |1      |null        |0      |
|user2|123       |1001        |1      |10001       |1      |
|user3|123       |1003        |1      |null        |0      |
|user4|123       |null        |0      |null        |0      |
|user5|123       |1004        |1      |10002       |1      |
+-----+----------+------------+-------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code implementation of the requirement

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
ll = [('test',123),('test',123),('test',123),('test',123)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(ll)
test1 = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(user=x[0], activityid=int(x[1])))
test1_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(test1)

mm = [('test',123,1001),('test',123,1002),('test',123,1003),('test',123,1004)]
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(mm)
test2 = rdd1.map(lambda x: Row(user=x[0], 
activityid=int(x[1]),event_time_1=int(x[2])))
test2_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(test2)

nn = [('test',123,10001),('test',123,10002)]
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(nn)
test3 = rdd2.map(lambda x: Row(user=x[0], 
activityid=int(x[1]),event_time_2=int(x[2])))
test3_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(test3)

from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.functions import dense_rank, rank

n = Window.partitionBy(test2_df.user,test2_df.activityid).orderBy(test2_df.event_time_1)
int2_df = test2_df.select("user","activityid","event_time_1",rank().over(n).alias("col_rank")).filter('col_rank = 1')

o = Window.partitionBy(test3_df.user,test3_df.activityid).orderBy(test3_df.event_time_2)
int3_df = test3_df.select("user","activityid","event_time_2",rank().over(o).alias("col_rank")).filter('col_rank = 1')

test1_df.distinct().join(int2_df,["user","activityid"],"leftouter").join(int3_df,["user","activityid"],"leftouter").show(10)

+----+----------+------------+--------+------------+--------+
|user|activityid|event_time_1|col_rank|event_time_2|col_rank|
+----+----------+------------+--------+------------+--------+
|test|       123|        1001|       1|       10001|       1|
+----+----------+------------+--------+------------+--------+
```